# Non-semisimple representation of vector spaces and of Lie Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Is it correct to say that a non semisimple representation of a vector space is a representation which is reducible and indecomposable?

If yes, how can this intuition be translated to the definition of a non semisimple Lie Algebra which, if I understand correctly, is a Lie Algebra with a non-trivial abelian ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a little misunderstanding here. Vector spaces don't have representations (at least not any that I am aware of). Do you mean a representation *on* a vector space?

More generally, semisimple means that it breaks up as the sum (or product, etc.) of 'simple' things. In the case of representations, simple means irreducible and in the case of Lie algebras simple means having no proper ideals.

These are sort of independent but it so happens that the (finite dimensional) representations of a semisimple Lie algebra are semisimple.

Edit: I said this last bit was true for all reductive Lie algebras but that is incorrect. Reductive means that the adjoint representation specifically is completely reducible (a.k.a. semisimple) while semisimple implies that all representations are.

Comment: I'm sorry! In physics we call the map and the target of the representation interchangeably as the representation itself! But I was indeed talking about an algebra representation on a vector space. In this case, does my claim hold? I'm specifically thinking about a triangular matrix representation, for instance, which appears to be reducible but non decomposable and, in particular, is non semisimple.

Comment: It is normal in maths to call the vector space itself a representation as well (though the more correct term would be module) but you wouldn't say a representation *of* a vector space. As to your claim (which I guess you mean non-semisimple implies reducible and indecomposable) then yes since semisimple means irreducible or decomposable into irreducible parts.

Comment: Note here I am assuming from context that reducible means it contains a **proper** invariant subspace under the representation. Careful as I'm not sure that is the universally agreed definition. In particular, "completely reducible" is usually a synonym for semisimple and so includes irreducible things.

Comment: you are right, the title is nonsensical. And the reducibility is defined with regards to a proper invariant subspace, indeed. And thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A (Lie algebra) representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ on a representation (vector) space $V$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism
$$
\varphi \, : \,\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V).
$$
Semisimplicity is a property on the left, i.e. at the Lie algebra level, and irreducibility is a property on the right, i.e. at the vector space level. Every finite-dimensional complex or real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ can be written as the semidirect sum of a semisimple Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ and its radical $\operatorname{rad}(\mathfrak{g}),$ i.e. its maximal solvable ideal
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\ltimes \operatorname{rad}(\mathfrak{g})
$$
$\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple iff $\operatorname{rad}(\mathfrak{g})=\{0\}.$

The representation is irreducible if the only vector subspaces $U\subseteq V$ such that $\varphi (\mathfrak{g})(U)\subseteq U$ are $U=\{0\}$ or $U=V.$

A Lie algebra, semisimple or not, can have reducible and irreducible representations.

The radical as the maximal solvable ideal contains an abelian ideal if it is not zero, and vice versa, any abelian ideal is part of the radical. So, yes, you can rewrite the definition of non-semisimplicity with Abelian ideals. However, the common definition is that $\operatorname{rad}(\mathfrak{g})\neq \{0\}.$

Comment: Thank you! But I believe that the semisimplicity of the representations themselves are usually defined too. I'd like to understand if my claim follows.